# Distributing different things into groups

Tags: combinatorics

How to distribute four different things in two groups..
Actual question was you have four different types of animals a wolf, a monkey, a tiger and a lion and you have two cages. Find No. Of ways of dividing them in this two cages.
I have attempted this question as follows . 
First we select two animals by 
(4  2)ways. Corrosponding to this each way we have
(4  2)ways for selecting two animals for second cage. So we get 
(4  2)*(4  2)=36 ways. But we need to divide this answer by 2! As there are 2 groups with same size . So answer is 36/2 =18 but given answer is 2^4 that is 16 
How could it be . Please explain

Comment: Do you need to have two animals in both cages, or can the animals be placed in any manner whatsoever? If there are no restrictions, you can decide the cage for each animal independently.

Comment: It is not given in question that you should have two animals in a cage.

Answer (score 0):

To get an answer of $2^4$, we want the cages to be distinct, red and blue. We can choose any **subset** of the set of $4$ animals to occupy the red cage. A $4$-element set has $2^4$ subsets.

But we don't really have to know that an $n$-element set has $2^n$ subsets (though this is a very important fact to know). Line up the animals in increasing order of student number. We have $2$ choices for the cage this animal goes into. For every such choice, there are $2$ choices for where the second animal goes, for a total of $2\times 2$. For every one of these $2\times 2$ choices, there are $2$ choices for where the third animal goes, and so on for a total of $2\times 2\times 2\times 2$.

**Remark:** If the cages are indistinguishable, the answer is different, and smaller. I am sure you can see how it should be modified.

Comment: Would you please elaborate further ?

Comment: About what? That a set of $n$ elements has $2^n$ subsets?

Comment: Yeah . Never understood sets completely !

Comment: I had added in a remark a way of counting that shows the answer for distinguishable cages is $2\times 2\times 2\times 2$. A generalization of that argument shows that an $n$-element set has $2^n$ subsets.

Comment: You are welcome. If the cages are indistinguishable, there are $8$ ways to do the job. But if they gave the answer as $16$, they must be thinking of the cages as distinguishable.